# xclock with nanosecond (or fractional second) resolution

Tags: time, clock

I currently run:

`xclock -digital -update 1 -strftime '%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S'`

and am reasonably happy with the resulting xclock, but don't find it quite annoying enough.

Is there any way I can add nanosecond (or decisecond, centisecond, millisecond, microsecond) precision? I tried adding a `%N` to the `-strftime` argument, but, unlike `date (GNU coreutils) 7.2`, it just gives me a literal '%N'.

I don't know what version of xclock I'm running and `xclock --version` is unhelpful, but this is the version that "ships with" Fedora Core 24 if that's helpful.

Comment: Just to point out even if you could add it xclock only supports refreshes in intervals of seconds.

Comment: Well, yes. I did try "-update 0.001" earlier only to get "Warning: Cannot convert string "0.001" to type Int", but I'm assuming a version of xclock that supports nanoseconds would allow for fractional updating. I also realize that, even on high end systems, it would have to skip over millions of nanoseconds per update. On my fairly new machine "repeat 2 date +%N" yields a difference of 2182678 nanoseconds (could run it multiple times and probably bring that number down a bit, but still)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wish` of TCL can solve this readily

```
#!/usr/bin/env wish8.5

set intervalms 1
variable theclock

proc setclock {} {
    global intervalms theclock
    set micros [clock microseconds]
    set epoch  [expr $micros / 1000000]
    set micros [format "%06d" [expr $micros % 1000000]]
    set theclock [clock format $epoch -format "%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S.$micros"]
    after $intervalms [list setclock]
}

font create TtyFont -family Courier -size 16 -weight bold
pack [label .clock -font TtyFont -textvariable theclock]

grid .clock -row 1 -column 1
grid rowconfigure . 1 -weight 1
grid columnconfigure . 1 -weight 1

wm geometry . 400x60+0+0

setclock
```

But if [annoying](https://github.com/thrig/scripts/blob/master/date-time/xrealclock) is your goal...

Comment: That is really beautiful, thank you! I actually meant with nanoseconds and updating as fast as possible, so I changed it to "set intervalms 1" and am sufficiently annoyed... but will check out the other link too. The only other change I'd make to yours is to have microseconds always take up exactly 6 digits (using sprintf or something)-- right now, the length of the date changes when the microsecond is less than 100000 (which I have to admit makes it even more annoying, but not quite in the way I wanted)